# ASP.Net MVC3 Data Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got the following C# code in an MVC3 Controller Action.

```
public ActionResult MyDocuments(int Page)
{
    int start = (Page==1?1:(Page-1)*4);
    int end = (Page==1?4:start + 4);
    // start parameter begins at 1
    Archive docs = mps.GetArchive(start, end);
    ViewBag.docs = docs;
    if (docs.Rows.Count() < 4)
    {
        ViewBag.lastPage = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.lastPage = 0;
    }   
    ViewBag.pagenum = Page;
    return View();
}
```

The issue I have is that it always starts the next page with the last entry from the previous page.

What am I doing wrong here? I do not know how many pages I will have, I only need to check the number returned in the docs object to see if it is < 4, then I set the ViewBag.lastPage value to disable the next btn in my View and the ViewBag.pagenum sets the pagenum value in the View to the current page number.

Comment: Page 1 shouldn't be a special case. Change your formula so it isn't.

Comment: Were you the one that downvoted this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your `mps.GetArchive(start, end)` method is returning all records between `start` and `end` inclusive. Normally the end value should be excluded.

If you can't change how the method works, call it as `mps.GetArchive(start, end - 1)`.